# Web2Py - How to make field enabled?

Tags: python, web2py

I have this form that gets built from the *SQLFORM* method,

```
flow_step_forms[step.name] = SQLFORM(db.approval_flows_progress_steps,
                                        record=thisstep.id if thisstep is not None else None,
                                        readonly=not __userCanPerformStep(step) or flow_completed)
```

the db for *approval_flows_progress_steps* is as follows

```
db.define_table('approval_flows_progress_steps', 
    Field('flow_progress', 'reference approval_flows_progress'),
    Field('flow_step', 'reference approval_flows_steps'),
    Field('completed', 'boolean'),
    Field('completed_on', 'datetime'),
    Field('completed_by', 'reference auth_user'),
    Field('notes', 'text', writable = True), 
    auth.signature
    )
```

the field *notes* gets rendered as a textbox.

After I assign the SQLFORM there is this code:

```
if __userCanPerformStep(step) and not flow_completed:
   flow_step_forms[step.name].element('textarea')['_rows'] = 5
```

I figured I can reference properties of the db like they do [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Storing-the-original-filename) but I get the following error: 
 **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'writable'**

Q: How can I make the text box conditionally enabled for certain users??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about why you are getting a NoneType. But to make the textarea readonly you can do something like this:

```
if __userCanPerformStep(step) and not flow_completed:
    flow_step_forms[step.name].element('textarea')['_readonly'] = True
else:
    flow_step_forms[step.name].element('textarea')['_readonly'] = False
```

If your NoneType problem is only occurring when the user is not authorized. You could catch it with a Try/Except block. Saying except NoneType: _readonly = True.